# Proving two lengths to be equal

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

Given this picture how do you proof that GJ=JA.
I am really stuck with this problem.
I know that you get 4 equilateral triangles, but I do not know how to proceed from here.
P.S. $AJ \parallel FG$.
[image]

Comment: Is $GF$ parallel to $JA$?

Comment: Yes they are parallel

Answer (score 1):

You could do it geometrically by noting that $\angle FGA = \angle GAJ$ (alternate angles are equal).
Then note that $IG = BG$ and that $AB = AI$.
$\therefore$ $ABGI$ is a kite.
Note that $AG$ is a diagonal and so it bisects $\angle BGI$.
So $\angle BGA = \angle AGI$.
So $\angle JGA = \angle JAG$.
Thus $GJ = JA$.

Or it can be done by calculating the gradient of $GF$ and the point $A (2, 2)$.
Then you can calculate the coordinates of $J$ and calculate $|GJ|$ and $|JA|$ and show that they are equal.

I personally prefer the first method but use whichever is easier and helps more.

Comment: + 1 simple and elegant

Comment: @GNUSupporter thanks for appreciating it. The key to solving these kinds of problems is to realize that everything is there for a reason, such as the circle and the two tangents. And to realize that sometimes drawing a single extra line solves the equation; in this case the line $GA$.

Comment: Plus there is one other trick: realizing the deeper meaning of things. Why do you think that only the y-intercept of the line $AJ$ was plotted. Figuring out things like that is difficult. Practice with this:                                                What do I mean when I say that differentiation is an integral part of maths?

Comment: As you say, everything in the figure comes with a reason.  My upvote also: I thought of $A=rs/2$ to calculate the height of origin from the hypotenuse of the great triangle, so I joined up $A$ and $I$ in some sense, but this leads to tedious calculations of side lengths.  That's why I find your way more simpler than mine.  $x$-intercept has no role to play in this deductive geometric proof, unlike an analytic geometric one. I'm not sure if I get the last question right. What's behind $d/dx$ can be written as an integral $\int f(x) dx$. When you see differentiation, there's an integral behind.

Comment: @GNUSupporter it was actually a (bad) pun about the $2$ different meanings of integral: $\int f(x) dx$ and important. The first meaning is actually the opposite of differentiation so that is where my (bad) pun intended :)

Comment: Interestingly, I don't see your upvote! Well that was you joking with me B)

Comment: P.S. could you show me those $4$ equilateral triangles. I could not find them.

Comment: I love telling jokes, but not lies.
 Once your rep ≥1000, you'll be able to see [upvotes vs downvotes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tv1n.png).  I think it should be “ isoceles” instead.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Oh okay thanks! But the P.S. part was directed to Zimo not you. I personally found the $4$ isosceles triangles but could not locate the $4$ equilateral triangles.

Answer (score 1):

Drop a perpendicular $JX $ from $J $ onto the line $FG $. Note triangles $\triangle GJX $ and $\triangle JAB $ are congruent, as both are right, $\angle JGX=\angle AJB $ and $AB=AI=JX $. Thus, $GJ=JA $ follows directly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all we can write a general function for a first order equation:

$$\text{y}\left(x\right):=\text{a}\cdot x+\text{b}\tag1$$

Now, we have two line:

- $$
  \begin{cases}
  \text{y}_1\left(0\right)=8=\text{a}_1\cdot0+\text{b}_1\\
  \\
  \text{y}_1\left(x\right)=0=\text{a}_1\cdot6+\text{b}_1
  \end{cases}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\therefore\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\begin{cases}
  \text{a}_1=-\frac{4}{3}\\
  \\
  \text{b}_1=8
  \end{cases}\tag2
  $$
- $$
  \begin{cases}
  \text{y}_2\left(2\right)=2=\text{a}_2\cdot2+\text{b}_2\\
  \\
  \text{a}_1=\text{a}_2=-\frac{4}{3}
  \end{cases}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\therefore\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\begin{cases}
  \text{a}_2=-\frac{4}{3}\\
  \\
  \text{b}_2=\frac{14}{3}
  \end{cases}\tag3
  $$

We can write $\text{a}_1=\text{a}_2$ because the lines are parallel.

Now, we can write:

$$\left|\text{GJ}\right|=\text{y}_1\left(0\right)-\text{y}_2\left(0\right)=-\frac{4}{3}\cdot0+8-\left(-\frac{4}{3}\cdot0+\frac{14}{3}\right)=\frac{10}{3}\tag4$$

And:

$$\left|\text{AJ}\right|=\sqrt{\left|\text{BJ}\right|^2+\left|\text{AB}\right|^2}=\sqrt{\left(\text{y}_2\left(0\right)-2\right)^2+2^2}=$$
$$\sqrt{\left(-\frac{4}{3}\cdot0+\frac{14}{3}-2\right)^2+2^2}=\frac{10}{3}\tag5$$

> DONE!